# sql server x64 access x86 COM object

Tags: sql-server

I want to transfer a database from SQL Server 2000 x86 to SQL Server 2008 R2 x64 but it uses a x86 COM object that I have no inside knowledge of.  I know there are some articles out there about the same topic, but my problem is slightly different.

After registering the DLL Server for Surrogate Activation, I can connect to COM object with sp_OACreate without errors, but sp_OASetProperty returns -2147352565 and sp_OAGetErrorInfo returns error source "ODSOLE Extended Procedure" and error description "Invalid index".